# How do I reference a video in harvard citation style using natbib?

Tags: bibliographies

I would like to reference a video in a paper that I am writing. The first problem is that I dont know which type of bibtex source I'm supposed to use. Is `@Misc` okey, you think?

Secondly, usually you include a URL if the video was found on some specific website. The problem in this case is that the the reader of my paper wont have access to the video if they're not having the same course as me, since the video is embedded in our course website. How am I going to go about this, in this case? Do I include the URL anyhow? Do I include some other information?

Comment: Yes, `misc` is probably the best type for this if you're using `natbib`. As for URLs, since I assume this is a paper for a course, linking to a course internal resource shouldn't be a problem. But surely the video in the course website has a source itself. Can't you link to that? Or is your professor in "do as I say, not what I do" mode?  :)

Comment: Ok, thanks! It could be that the video has some other external source, I will look it up. My professor is mostly in the "do as I say, not what I do" mode, hehe.